# Linked text in Text Area in Java

Tags: java, swing, url, richtextbox, jtextarea

I need user be able to enter text in input form's Text Area and be able to make clickable links in some part of that text (Links are inserted by a button in form and are references to other places in application and are not WWW links).
How can I do this?
Is there any component for this?

Comment: Please have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462725/actionlistener-for-a-specific-text-inside-a-jtextarea/10463120#10463120).         I think you can use, [modelToView(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TextUI.html#modelToView(javax.swing.text.JTextComponent, int)) and [viewToModel(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TextUI.html#viewToModel(javax.swing.text.JTextComponent, java.awt.Point)), for this case.

Comment: I already up-voted nice cow's answer. Can't do it again. :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson :  hehe, thankx :-), I did right clicked them. Seems like some issues with spacing . Seems to me, whenever there are brackets in the link, it happens this way, though if I won't put this in comments and put this answers instead, then this won't happen. Then they will format as expected :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw If you paste the ' right click copied' URL in a little utility and convert it to URI it should also work for answer or comment.  I just open the page though..  Tips I picked up from the Usenet days.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I didn't meant any particular component; I just want to make it done (with any possible component) & I used Text Area as a general phrase! anyway I think you're right and it made some misunderstandings so I did some space jobs. Thanks

Comment: Good edit.  That is more clear.  :)