# Getting Caret position from JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, document, jtextarea, caret

I can get row number and column number from Jtextarea by using,

```
   int caretpos = textArea.getCaretPosition();
   int row = textArea.getLineOfOffset(caretpos);

   int column = caretpos - textArea.getLineStartOffset(row);
```

How can i get the caret position from row number and column number?

Comment: I guess you are looking for this line `int startOffset = tarea.viewToModel(new Point(x, y));`. Your **row and column** variables can act as **x and y** respectively, in the example that proceeds. For more info have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463120/1057230)

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali please I'm sure that you know that better, then this comment should be nice answer :-)

Comment: @mKorbel : I just realized, though the example can give answer to the end question that arises, as to how to insert a String at a specified location by the OP, in another thread, though how to calculate the `CaretPosition` is a bit tricky :-)

Answer (score 2):

for both your questions, answer could be deleted

- [Document is Model for JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html)
- you can to determine int start / end for every row(s)
- you can to determine int start / end for `Caret` by `CaretListener`
- for listening of changes from view is there `DocumentListener`
- for preventing / modifying of input is there `DocumentFilter`