# Generate a clickable event from a text area

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, click, jtextarea

I want to generate a clickable event from text area which contains a list of names of people. When we click on a certain name it must make a call to a method (which in turn is going to display the details of that person from a XML file).

Is this possible with text area? I have heard about `JTextPane`, but I need some other option.

Comment: how about using a JList?

Comment: *"need some other option"*  Don't be vague.  List the entire & complete requirement for this component.

Comment: JTree would be a better choice for displaying the contents of an XML file - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Usually I would agree with you, but it seems this XML is used to wrap a list, so I'm leaning toward `JList`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson With out seeing the actually data, either would be suitable, but I agree, JList is an option

Comment: Hopefully this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463120/1057230) is what, you talking about...

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible. Use `viewToModel()` method to get offset for the clicked point. Then use `Utilities` to `getWordStart/getWordEnd` methods to get the clicked name. Then just pass the name into desired function.