# Set mouse click event on text?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have a project where some random text is displayed in a JScrollPane. This text is coded in and is not editable. Is there a way to create a mouse click event on each line of text and have that event take the text clicked on and have it display in a textField?

The part that stumps me is how to act on a line of text versus a clickevent on a button per se. Below is a rendering of the project and the areas containing the text.

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like it should be done as a JList. I recommend looking here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: Might be this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463120/1057230) be of some help on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your text is displayed in a JTextArea or JTextPane, so you would add a MouseListener to the component. Then when the MouseEvent is generated you can get the caret position. Using the caret position you can then use the `Utilities` class. It has methods like:

1. `getRowStart(...)`
2. `getRowEnd(...)`

Using these values you can then get the text from the `Document` using the `getText(...)` method.